# How do I compute items from a list in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

New here and in the process of learning Python.

I am running through a scenario of taking office temperatures for the day. Anything above 16 is placed into a second list where I would like to work out the percentages. For example; 5 / 8 * 100 = 62%

Here is what I currently have:

```
# List of temperatures taken from the office
list_temp = [16, 32, 5, 40, 10, 19, 38, 15]

# Output list above 16 degree celsius
output = []
total_output = 0

for position in list_temp:
    if position >= 16:
        output = output + [position]

print('Printing list of Temp Above 16', output)
```

Now my question is, and believe me I have Googled the life out of this the past couple days. How do I take the "output" list and do the percentage formula as above?

I have tried to create it in the for loop but to no avail.

Comment: What are those percentages supposed to be? Your example doesn't explain it

Comment: Note the indents in the post - something probably has gone wrong when you were creating the post - as it is now, the code wouldn't even execute due to the invalid indent after the `for` loop definition.

Comment: `100.0 * sum(1 for x in list_temp if x >= 16) / len(list_temp)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create the list with only temps greater than 16, the easiest way is to use a list comprehension:

```
output = [temp for temp in list_temp if temp >= 16]
```

The above is equivalent to:

```
output = []
for temp in list_temp:
    if temp >= 16:
        output.append(temp)
```

Then, to get the ratio:

```
percentage = len(output) / len(list_temp) * 100
print(percentage) # 62.5
```

Comment: I knew it had to be using the len() statement, I get somewhat confused on how Python flows. It is a huge learning curve but I will get there, in the end, we have all been there I am sure :-) Thank you for the help here I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `len()` to get the number of items in both lists and calculate a percentage from that.

```
>>>print('Percentage: ' + str(len(output)/len(list_temp)*100) + '%')
Percentage: 62.5%
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the list comprehension to build your list with elements:

```
list_temp = [16, 32, 5, 40, 10, 19, 38, 15]

lower = [i for i in list_temp if i >= 16] #your second list

percentage = len(lower)/len(list_temp) * 100
percentage
>>62.5
```

Then just get the percentage from the lengths.